# When to use BindAttribute?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning asp.net mvc and wonder when we need to use `BindAttribute`.

The first case (using `Bind`):

Model:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Create([Bind(nameof(Book.Name), nameof(Book.Author))] Book model)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

The book `Id` would be generated on server side. So, client side has nothing to do with it, every actions try to change/make the id is prevented.

The second case (not using `Bind`):

Model:

```
public class BookViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Create(BookViewModel model)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Because the second model doesn't contain `Id` property, we don't need to prevent from creating or changing.

I prefer the second. It's easy to manage model.

Is there a case we `must` use `Bind` attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use bind when we want that some properties of complex property are ignored when received on server. It could be for safety or other reasons.

When this action is executed the MVC model binder will use the request parameters to populate the `user` parameter's properties, as you may already know. However, the `Bind` attribute tells the model binder to **only** populate properties with names specified.

So in this case only the `Username`, `FullName` and `Email` properties will be populated. All others will be ignored.

See here for more details: http://ittecture.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/tip-of-the-day-199-asp-net-mvc-defining-model-binding-explicitly/

If you have situation when you only have to ignore one parametar from binding you could use `Exclude` property:

```
[Exclude] 
public Entity Name {get; set;}
```

Comment: Thanks! Should I avoid using it? Because I think if a model contains about 10 properties (9/10 properties need), it would make the code looks harder to read. `[Bind(nameof(MyModel.Property1), nameof(MyModel.Property2), nameof(MyModel.Property3), nameof(MyModel.Property4)..........)]`

Comment: If you have "9/10 situation" you could use Exclude property. I updated my answer expaining this.

Comment: I will remember it although asp.net core doesn't support `Exclude` attribute. Thanks!

Comment: @clone - in asp.net core see [BindNever](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.bindneverattribute) attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Bind is used to increase security and unauthorized data to be posted on server . In your model class , suppose you have content property also. if the content property is not needed in the future. Then it would be difficult for you to remove all the occurrences of that property. Here you can use bind property like this

```
[Bind(exclude="content")]
```

or you can bind only selected properties to be posted on server by including the properties like this

```
 public ActionResult create([Bind(Include = "Name,Author")] Modelclass modelclass)
{
//Do something here
}
```

You can learn more about it  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Second approach is more suitable instead writing all the properties and bind them but there are some situations where you must bind user like you have a roles property or IsAdmin property in your model then you might not want that user somehow posts the IsAdmin or roles properties to the server . That's where you can use Bind attribute